# Android: dialog and AsyncTask - why am I getting an IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got an Activity like this:

```
public class StudentActivity extends Activity {
static final int DIALOG_PROGRESS = 0;

public void btnSyncStudentsClick(View view) {
    syncStudents();
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog d = null;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_PROGRESS:
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.txt_refreshing_students));
        d = dialog;
        break;

    return d;
}

private class RefreshStudentTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, AccountRefreshResult> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected AccountRefreshResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //some network requests
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AccountRefreshResult result) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);             //this throws an exception

        //some other stuff
    }
}   
}
```

Since the dialog is shown in onPreExecute() and dismissed in onPostExecute(), I don't know why some of the users get an exception:

```
Uncaught exception handled :/ , thread: Thread[main,5,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 0 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
    at android.app.Activity.missingDialog(Activity.java:2606)
    at android.app.Activity.dismissDialog(Activity.java:2591)
    at pl.mobireg.eparent.activities.StudentActivity$RefreshStudentTask.onPostExecute(StudentActivity.java:390)
    at pl.mobireg.eparent.activities.StudentActivity$RefreshStudentTask.onPostExecute(StudentActivity.java:364)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I cannot replicate this issue on my side, so it is very hard to debug.

EDIT:
Activity should only run in portrait mode:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Is your dialog showing..? it says it is not showing..

Comment: on my device it is showing. I don't know how about the problematic device. I've got only the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably replicate this by doing whatever starts the dialog and then changing orientation as the activity will get recreated then without the dialog. This is one of the many annoyances with dealing with dialogs and as such, Google has recommended that you use [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead as it manages a lot of these edge cases for you.

Comment: well the activity should only run in portrait mode (see my edited post)

Comment: Is the `ProgressDialog` cancelable? What happens when you press the back button when it's up?

Comment: yes it is cancelable but pressing 'back' doesn't replicate the bug

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog was already dismissed.  This is a moderately common race condition.  Just catch the exception and move on, the result is the same either way-  the dialog is gone.

Comment: but there is only one dismissDialog() call and it should always run after showDialog(). How can it be dismissed?

Comment: Orientation change (or other configuration change) causing your activity to be restarted would be one way (async tasks aren't automatically canceled, so it would finish up, but have a handle to a dead dialog).  But regardless this is a safe one to ignore-  you want the dialog to go away, its gone away.